# Apply Function for Text Cleaning to Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, python-applymap

I have three columns of text in my dataframe that I want to apply the same function to.  Here is what I have tried below.  What should I pass as a parameter to my function?

```
def clean_columns():
     df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace('[^\w\s]',' ')\
                  .str.replace('hello',' ')\
                  .str.replace('goodbye',' ')\
                  .str.lower()\
                  .str.split()
df[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']].applymap(clean_columns)
```

I am not sure how to write the function in a way were it takes in each column separately and applies the function to it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the function as

```
def clean_columns(col):
    return col.str.replace('[^\w\s]',' ')\
                  .str.replace('hello',' ')\
                  .str.replace('goodbye',' ')\
                  .str.lower()\
                  .str.split()
```

and use apply only:

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']] = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].apply(clean_column)
```

Comment: I am getting below error when I apply my function on mulitple columns. If I apply it individually it works fine. Any suggestions about how I can fix this? *************************************** "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."